# How to draw a line between Astrophysics and Physics, if there is any posibility?

Tags: discussion, scope, physics.se

There is not really much to say. Ideas?

Comment: Here is a good blog post on this topic — **[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)**

Answer (score 15):

Quoting [myself](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-do-we-draw-the-line-concerning-planetary-science-questions/8#8)

> We don't need to. It's perfectly OK for sites to have an overlap.
>   Migrations should only be done if:
>
> - The question is *off topic* on the source site
> - If not, it still may be migrated on OPs request
> - If it is borderline on topic on the source site and doesn't get answers, again it can be migrated.
>
> No need to draw a line. It's fine if more than one site gets a piece
>   of the pie.

Comment: Great answer - each site should allow the questions that its community needs. In some cases, the same exact question on "just physics" may get wildly different answers on a site full of astrophysicists, because they're collectively focused on a different part of the answer that's more relevant in an astronomical context.

Answer (score 3):

But clearly there questions which do exist which are far better suited for a physics stack exchange site. If people ask questions regarding circuit diagrams on the astronomy stack exchange site, that would be bad. There are mutually exclusive regions, and the tricky part is determining what those are. Optics is clear example of this overlap - blocks on inclined planes are not.